# Scala convert a DateTime value to Timestamp

Tags: scala, datetime

maybe it is a duplicated question, I tried to find a solution but no way.

Problem : convert a DateTime instance to Timestamp.

My DateTime instance is created as :

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime
    val start = (new DateTime).withYear(2016)
       .withMonthOfYear(12)
       .withDayOfMonth(1)
       .withMinuteOfHour(0)
       .withHourOfDay(0)
```

with println of this date, I got :

```
2016-12-01T00:00:18.856+01:00
```

What I need is like Epoch timestamp in picture bellow :
[image]

Comment: Do you need JodaTime or can you use Java (8++) time?

Comment: I am using JodaTime.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO one of the fastest way to calculate the Epoch timestamp is:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def epochDayForYear(year: Int): Long =
  365L * year + (((year + 3) >> 2) - (if (year < 0) {
    val century = year * 1374389535L >> 37 // divide int by 100 (a sign correction is not required)
    century - (century >> 2)
  } else ((year + 99) * 1374389535L >> 37) - ((year + 399) * 1374389535L >> 39))) // divide int by 100 and by 400 accordingly (a sign correction is not required)

def dayOfYearForYearMonth(year: Int, month: Int): Int =
  ((month * 1050835331877L - 1036518774222L) >> 35).toInt - // == (367 * month - 362) / 12
    (if (month <= 2) 0
    else if (isLeap(year)) 1
    else 2)

def isLeap(year: Int): Boolean = (year & 3) == 0 && {
  val century = (year * 1374389535L >> 37).toInt - (year >> 31) // divide int by 100
  century * 100 != year || (century & 3) == 0
}

def secondOfDay(hour: Int, month: Int, day: Int): Int = 
  hour * 3600 + month * 60 + day

val (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZoneOffsetHour, timeZoneOffsetMinute) = 
  (2016, 12, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)

val epochSecond = 
  (epochDayForYear(year) + (dayOfYearForYearMonth(year, month) + day - 719529)) * 86400 + 
  secondOfDay(hour + timeZoneOffsetHour, minute + timeZoneOffsetMinute, second) // where 719528 is days 0000 to 1970

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

epochDayForYear: (year: Int)Long
dayOfYearForYearMonth: (year: Int, month: Int)Int
isLeap: (year: Int)Boolean
secondOfDay: (hour: Int, month: Int, day: Int)Int
year: Int = 2016
month: Int = 12
day: Int = 1
hour: Int = 0
minute: Int = 0
second: Int = 2
timeZoneOffsetHour: Int = 0
timeZoneOffsetMinute: Int = 0
epochSecond: Long = 1480550402
```

BTW, most of this code is borrowed from the [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/ca962bbe9e919a08c4be8b3da97f53221669ea8f/jsoniter-scala-core/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/core/JsonReader.scala#L1828-L1837) project.

Answer (score 0):

First: Scala gets compiled into Java, so when you are asking a question about a Java library you can use examples from that.

Second: Do you have any default Timezone in your application? I would put this in a logical place (i.e. when you start you application / in some config)

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Now you can just create a new java.sql.Timestamp like this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant

  val start = (new DateTime).withYear(2016)
   .withMonthOfYear(12)
   .withDayOfMonth(1)
   .withMinuteOfHour(0)
   .withHourOfDay(0)

  val timestamp = new Timestamp(start.getMillis()) : Timestamp

  // To get the epoch timestamp, take a look at java.time.Instant

  val epochTimestamp =  timestamp.toInstant() : Instant
```

More information here: https://www.jeejava.com/conversion-of-joda-date-time-to-sql-timestamp-and-vice-versa/

Comment: I got 2016-12-01 01:00:05.612 instead of a timestamp value!

Comment: `2016-12-01 01:00:05.612` is a Timestamp. What format do you want your timestamp in?

Comment: There you go. I would suggest looking at `java.time.Instant` @samara

Answer (score 0):

Using java.time. Does this help?

```
scala> val x = java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(System.currentTimeMillis/1000,0,java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
x: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-11-21T18:41:29

scala> java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-21T18:41:29.123").toEpochSecond(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
res41: Long = 1542825689

scala> java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-21T18:41:29.123").format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eeee, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
res61: String = Wednesday, November 21, 2018 06:41:29 PM

scala>
```

This link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html might be helpful to know the symbols used in the format options